# Liferay 6.2 add jars in Portal dependency

Tags: jar, liferay, ivy, build-dependencies

in liferay-plugin-package.properties there is Portal Dependency section in which i can add jar to the portlet.

I want to add gson-2.2.4 and jersey-bundle but these jar are not into the list. I want to add this jars to my project, possible using Ivy.  My goal is to use maven style so write the dependency and ivy download the jar. I've tried adding

```
< dependency name="gson" org="com.google.code.gson" rev="2.2.4" />
< dependency name="jersey-bundle" org="com.sun.jersey" rev="1.18.1" />
```

into ivy.xml but without success.

Comment: Try adding manually the jar into lib folder? Why not?

Answer (score 0):

That only gets ivy to download the jars locally. Now go ahead and navigate to liferay-plugin-sdk directory and copy the jar files from the .ivy folder and paste then in `<Your-Project-portlet>/lib`. Go to project properties, then Java Build Path. In the libraries tab, click `Add JARs` and navigate to `<your-project>/lib` and add them.